# The Fine Structure of The Constructible Hierarchy

Tags: set-theory, reference-request

I hold in my hand a printout of Jensen's article from Annals of Mathematical Logic 4 (1972) named as in the title of the question.

However the quality of the .pdf I found was very bad and it is very hard to read it, furthermore the article was written in days before LaTeX and the symbols are non-standard for current articles (e.g. $\bigwedge$ for $\forall$ and such).

Moreover, I was told that there is some mistake somewhere in the beginning of the article, it is not a grave mistake, some result that he doesn't prove there. But it is a mistake nonetheless.

Regardless to the two problems, I was told that this is a very good article for studying the topic.

Is there a "digitally remastered" version somewhere online with the error(s) corrected and a clearer typeset?

(I got mine from the ScienceDirect website)

[I'm not sure that this is the place for this question, however I have no idea where would be the place for it. Any comments and/or directions about this issue would be most welcomed]

Comment: Keith Devlin's *Constructibility* is a more recent reference which contains much of Jensen's early results.

Comment: @Francois: Do you mean http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235419477 ?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: I'll see what my advisor thinks about that. Thanks!

Comment: There are several other intros to fine structure theory, e.g., some chapters of the Handbook of Set theory, or L. Stanley: A short course on gap-one morasses with a review of the fine structure of L.  Surveys in set theory,  197--243,
London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 87, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1983. 

Comment: Unfortunately there are probably more grave errors in Devlin's book, than in Jensen's original paper (where there are few/none). They occur mostly in the first part in his development of the basic theory from his system BS.  The fine structural development is fine tho'. 

If you consult Mathias "Some Weak Systems of Gandy,Jensen, and Devlin" (http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/weaksystems.dvi)
this lists, and corrects, the errors in Devlin.